# GPA weightage for changing fields in higher studies

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, gpa

Currently pursuing my 3rd year of  BTech in electronics and communication engineering, I plan on pursuing an Integrated PhD / PhD in Astronomy and Astrophysics due to my deep interest and passion for th field.

I have relevant research experience in the same, good GRE scores and LORs.

My question is that due to the change in my study field, how much weightage will my engineering GPA have on my application? If it is average, will it be a drawback?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suspect that your change in direction will matter very little to the admissions committee as long as you can provide evidence of your passion for the new one. I don't think many admissions committees use formal weights for GPA, GRE, LOR.

Answer (score 3):

A good GPA, etc, will give evidence that you work hard. That won't be an issue in the new field. But the admissions process/committee will need some assurance that you have the necessary prerequisite courses and knowledge in that new field or can quickly pick that up. That will weigh more heavily, perhaps. So, other things, such as the indicated research, and letters will be helpful.